# Ubuntu desktop slightly too big on HDMI TV

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

When I connect my Panasonic Viera TV (720p) via HDMI to my notebook the desktop is cut on the TV. I tried different resolutions but no matter which it's always cut on each side...
I had the same problem on Windows 7 but managed to correct it with the resolution of 1184x666. When I try this with xrandr (I manually added and activated this mode) on Ubuntu (12.10, also on 12.04) it just gives me a blank screen.

I found a couple of posts that deal with the same problem and tried out the suggested solutions but nothing works. In the meanwhile I think it's the problem of the TV. But then if it works on Windows, why not on Ubuntu?

Details for TV:
Panasonic LCD TV TX-L32X10E

Comment: Try to find `overscan` in your TV settings and turn it off. Can you edit your post with the exact model of TV you have?

Comment: thx! I added the model... Can't find "overscan" on TV...

Comment: It could be something like `Menu --> Picture --> Advanced Picture --> HD Size` and set it to `2`.

Comment: I got "Menu", i got "Picture", but no "Advanced Picture" option or something similar...

Comment: found "overscan" on some other menu and turned it off... will try Ubuntu now; thx in the meanwhile!!

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a overscan issue. Do you have proprietary drivers installed? If so, you could perhaps fix it with something like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtFKfz2Ptt0

From the manual pages on your TV, it would seem like such an option could be found under:
Setup -> Other Settings -> Picture Overscan-

Comment: found it and will try it out! for now thx a lot people!

Answer (score 4):

ubuntu 12.04 x64 out-of-the-box installation make headache for me
ati/amd drivers not work like before i have radeon hd 4650 (or something) :)
search internet many days no resolution anywhere only help installing ati drivers.
(that not work) my card not supported anymore and need downgrade something
xorg and some other don't remember but i dont know how downgrade lol im linux noob
and like ubuntu bcoz its so easy install allways and just playing around with it.
still using windows 7 dayly. reason is when install something on linux system can get broken and not run anymore and only way to correct is clean install.
happen so many time..

fix i found is this and this should be on ubuntu site!?!? (front page maybe lol)

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set underscan on
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have already mentioned, you need to disable overscan.

**However**, you might **also** need to manually set the aspect to 16:9 before you can even get to the overscan option. Some TVs (including Panasonic Viera TVs) automatically hide the overscan option if the aspect is not manually set to 16:9.

So if you are struggling to find the overscan option in your TV settings, try setting the aspect to 16:9.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn of `overscan`. This can be done trough your TV settings. The location can be found in the manual.

In your case it's probably:

```
Setup > Other Settings > Picture Overscan
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and a Sanyo TV.

After an update or something, the top panel moved off the top of the mirrored display, so I could only see it on the laptop monitor.

The fix for me was to adjust the 'vertical pos' from 50 to 25 in the TV picture menu, *when you're in the D-SUB input source mode* of the TV (because the 'screen' sub-menu is available when you're using the DTV input source).

Top panel not visible on mirrored display D-SUB output
    On the TV, in the D-SUB mode:
        Menu.Picture(tab).Screen.Vertical Pos   = 25 (instead of 50)